# Jquery checkbox selection iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
$('.tg tr.data-list-row[name=data-list-row]').click(function() {               
       var currentId = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
       $.getJSON('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/ws/booking/getpriceinput_by_id/' + currentId, function(data) {
           $("#current_typetarif_id").val(data.id);
           $("#inputName").val(data.libelle);
           $("#inputCode").val(data.code);
           $("#inputTarif").val(data.montantTarifDefaut);     

           $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i) {
                $("#option_tarif_chk_" + data.tarifTypeOptionList[0].tarifOptionId).prop('checked', true);
            });
       });            
});
```

I have the following code which fetch data from the following JSON below:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "code": "0001",
  "libelle": "TARIF PUBLIC",
  "montantTarifDefaut": 10.00,
  "tarifTypeList": [
    {
      "chambreTypeId": 1,
      "tarifTypeId": 1
    }
  ],
  "tarifTypeOptionList": [
    {
      "typeTarifId": 1,
      "tarifOptionId": 1
    },
    {
      "typeTarifId": 1,
      "tarifOptionId": 2
    },
    {
      "typeTarifId": 1,
      "tarifOptionId": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

I have to use `data.tarifTypeOptionList[0]` so that it returns me the value, but look like the iteration is not working and it is returning only the first value which is:

```
 {
    "typeTarifId": 1,
    "tarifOptionId": 1
 },


<form class="form-horizontal" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 150px;" id="scrollit" name="thisForm">
                        <c:forEach items="${option_tarif_list}" var="option_tarif" varStatus="loop">
                            <div class="checkbox1">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="tarif_inclue" value="${option_tarif.libelle}" class="checkboxchk" id="option_tarif_chk_${option_tarif.id}">
                                    ${option_tarif.libelle}
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </c:forEach>
<!--                        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="loopForm(document.thisForm);">
                        <div id="cbResults"></div>-->
                    </form>
```

HTML Table row:

```
<table class="table tg" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 745px">
                <colgroup>
                <col style="width: 249px">
                <col style="width: 249px">
                <col style="width: 249px">

                </colgroup>

                <thead>
                    <tr>
                       <th class="tg-s6z2 bdleft">NOM</th>
                       <th class="tg-s6z2">CODE</th>
                       <th class="tg-s6z2">PRIX PAR DEFAUT</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">
                        <div class="scrollit">
                            <table class="table tg" style="table-layout: fixed;">
                                <colgroup>
                                <col style="width: 220px">
                                <col style="width: 240px">
                                <col style="width: 240px">
                                </colgroup>


                                <c:forEach items="${type_tarif_list}" var="type_tarif" varStatus="loop">  
                                  <tr class="data-list-row" name="data-list-row" id="${type_tarif.id}" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                    <td class="tg-s6z2 bdleft">${type_tarif.libelle}</td>
                                    <td class="tg-s6z2">${type_tarif.code}</td>
                                    <td class="tg-s6z2">${type_tarif.montantTarifDefaut}</td>
                                    <td class="deleterow bdryt" id="${type_tarif.id}" name="del_button"><div class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" title="Supprimer"></div></td>
                                  </tr>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

How can i make sure to get all the values inside this iteration? I thought the `.each()` method will do the job, but it's not. Please help spot what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('input[type="checkbox"]')` will iterate through the all `checkboxes`, instead of that try to iterate through the `tarifTypeOptionList`, so it will give you the current object, by using same we can set `checked` property `true`.

```
$('.tg tr.data-list-row[name=data-list-row]').click(function() {               
   var row = $(this).closest('tr'), currentId =  row.attr('id');

   // to uncheck the previous row checkboxes
```

<del>row.siblings().find(".checkboxchk").prop('checked', false);</del>

```
   // this will uncheck the all checkboxes with class name `checkboxchk` before setting the `checked` to true of the selected row checkboxes.
   $(".checkboxchk").prop('checked', false);

   $.getJSON('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/ws/booking/getpriceinput_by_id/' + currentId, function(data) {
       $("#current_typetarif_id").val(data.id);
       $("#inputName").val(data.libelle);
       $("#inputCode").val(data.code);
       $("#inputTarif").val(data.montantTarifDefaut);     

       // to check the current row checkboxes using json data
       $.each(data.tarifTypeOptionList, function(i, obj) {
           $("#option_tarif_chk_" + obj.tarifOptionId).prop('checked', true);
       });

   });            
});
```

Comment: Yes this does work as well. Thank you very much.

Can you help me make an if condition so that the result obtained from the first id is unchecked and only the result of the second id is displayed once i click on the second row?

Comment: @Fadil you mean if click on the second row, then previous row `checkbox` should be unchecked ??

Comment: yes exactly @Srinu.

i think maybe an if condition will work ya :/

Comment: I have wrote something like this:

$.each(data.tarifTypeOptionList, function(i, obj) {
                    if($("#option_tarif_chk_" + obj.tarifOptionId).prop('checked')==true)
                        $("#option_tarif_chk_" + obj.tarifOptionId).prop('checked', false);
                    else
                        $("#option_tarif_chk_" + obj.tarifOptionId).prop('checked', true);
                });

But the issue is that i need to click again on the row to uncheck the values, then move on to the second one

Comment: try this $(this).closest('tr').siblings().find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false);. It will uncheck the siblings rows `checkbox`. Note: place outside of the `each` loop.

Comment: Is this what you meant:

$.each(data.tarifTypeOptionList, function(i, obj) {
                    $("#option_tarif_chk_" + obj.tarifOptionId).prop('checked', true);
                });
                $(this).closest('tr').siblings().find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false);

It didnt worked.

Comment: can you show html code, so that i can provide you the better solution

Comment: I tried your given code @Srinu, but it didnt work. It still works as before...not unchecking the checkbox once the next row is clicked.

Comment: if possible paste table row structure

Comment: @Fadil  clickable table  and checkboxes are placed different blocks? is so then the previous statement will not work, in that case to uncheck the checkboxes we can use the class selector `$(".checkboxchk").prop('checked', false);` this will uncheck the all checkboxes.

Comment: yes they are in different blocks. Can you be more precise what i need to do please. Thank you.

Comment: Ouff thank you @Srinu. Yes it works now. 

Thank a lot for your help.

Comment: Hi again @Srinu

The code you gave me actually works. But i have an issue with it. I think i still need the if condition because when i'm now unchecking a checkbox and inserting it into the database, it doesn't identify the unchecked checkbox and give an error.

Can you please help me with the if condition.

Thank you

Comment: So far i wrote something like this

$.each(data.tarifTypeOptionList, function(i, obj) {
                    if('input[name="tarif_inclue"]'){
                        $("#option_tarif_chk_" + obj.tarifOptionId).prop('checked', true);
                    }
                    else{
                        $(".checkboxchk").prop('checked', false);
                    }
                });

Comment: modified it to this

if($('input:checkbox[name=tarif_inclue]').is(':checked')){
                    $(".checkboxchk").prop('checked', false);
                }
                else{
                    $.each(data.tarifTypeOptionList, function(i, obj) {
                        $("#option_tarif_chk_" + obj.tarifOptionId).prop('checked', true);
                    });
                }

Answer (score 1):

Try using data.tarifTypeOptionList[i] inseted of using data.tarifTypeOptionList[0]

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i) {
  $("#option_tarif_chk_" + data.tarifTypeOptionList[i].tarifOptionId).prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt answer, yes it worked :)

Can you help me make an if condition so that the result obtained from the first id is unchecked and only the result of the second id is displayed once i click on the second row?

Comment: what if you just use radio button instead of a checkbox?

Comment: I cant because there are variious values which will be displayed once a table row is clicked.

And also, i'm supposed to be able to make various item selection from the checkbox and save it in the JSON.

So radio button is not an option.